# VBA: Create new document from template, search and replace text

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word

after I have now tried myself a whole day on it and have not found the right solution, the forum is my last hope.

What do I want to achieve?
I have a Word template (.dotm file), based on which I create a new document.
In the new document I want to replace a certain text with another value.
The file should then be saved with the replaced text.

This works already:

- Create the new file
- Saving the new file

The following happens when I try to replace text:
The text to be replaced is replaced in the template. The new file remains untouched.

What have I tried to solve the problem?

- Activate the Word instance where the new document is.
- Set Selection and Range (difficult for me to control if the correct one is in the Selection Object or not).

This is what my code looks like:

```
'Platzierungsdatei öffnen
Set excel = CreateObject("excel.application")
excel.Workbooks.Open FileName:=pfadUrkunden

'Word Instanz öffnen
Dim wdDocument As Object
Dim Word As Object
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 
Do While excel.Worksheets("TN").Cells(iIndex, 1).Value <> ""
    sName = excel.Worksheets("TN").Cells(iIndex, 1).Value
     
    Set wdDocument = Word.Documents.Add(vorlagePfad)
    Word.Visible = True
    '[Vorname Nachname] ersetzen
    Word.Activate
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Textfeld 2")).Select
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[Vorname Nachname]"
        .Replacement.Text = sName
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
     
    ausgabeOrdner = ausgabeOrdner & "\" & sName
    wdDocument.SaveAs (ausgabeOrdner)

    '+55 um nur einen Eintrag zu testen
    iIndex = iIndex + 55
Loop
 
Word.Quit
Set Word = Nothing

excel.Quit
```

I have Office 365 and am trying to run the program from the .dotm file.

I ask for help and appreciate any ideas!

Sorry for the German comments in my code, feel free to ask questions :)

Thanks a lot already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code that you have posted it would be impossible to change anything in the template, *unless you already have the template open and it is the active document*.

Your code is a confused mess as it switches between `wdDocument`, `ActiveDocument` and `Selection`.

`ActiveDocument` should be replaced with `wdDocument` as that is the document your code is supposed to be working with. This removes any possibility of confusion with other open documents, and avoids the need to activate the working document.

`Selection` is best avoided as there is rarely any need to select anything when working in VBA. As you won't be selecting anything there is no need to make Word visible.

```
Set wdDocument = Word.Documents.Add(vorlagePfad)
'[Vorname Nachname] ersetzen
With wdDocument.Shapes("Textfeld 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[Vorname Nachname]"
    .Replacement.Text = sName
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```